# Firebase Facebook Authentication publishing

Tags: swift, firebase, facebook, authentication

So I am trying to incorporate facebook login to firebase app. I can log in only with my developer facebook account. Do I need to publish my app on facbook developer so that I can use facebook log in for firebase?

Since I didnt see any tutorial doing it, and to publish I need to have business account for facebook, I would want to not publish it but use log in function of facebook for my firebase app

Comment: Yes, you will need to get your app, and its use of permissions & features, approved in review. Before you do that, only people with a role in the app will be able to use it. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/release